# SVG animateTransform with href

Tags: javascript, svg

Trying to move an SVG element using javascript for an interactive game;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg width="300" height="300">
            <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"   fill="black" ></circle>
            <animateTransform xlink:href="#circ" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="50 50" to="200 200" dur="1s" repeatCount="1"></animateTransform>
        </svg> 
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the element drops back to its original position after the animation.

Any suggestions to make the element stay put in the new position?
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [fill](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#TimingAttributes)="freeze" if you want the final animation state to apply after the animation has ended.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <svg width="300" height="300">
       <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"   fill="black" >
       </circle>

       <animateTransform xlink:href="#circ" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="50 50" to="200 200" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"></animateTransform>
    </svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <svg width="300" height="300">
       <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"   fill="black" >
       </circle>

       <animateTransform xlink:href="#circ" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="50 50" to="200 200" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" ></animateTransform>
    </svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

You just required to use fill freeze.